# Finding the difference in years between consecutive rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate the date difference between consecutive rows based on an indicator_id to find cases where the difference is not be more than 3 years.

```
year                             indicator_id
--------------------------      ---------------
January 1, 1999, 12:00 AM             1
January 1, 2000, 12:00 AM             1
January 1, 2001, 12:00 AM             1
January 1, 2006, 12:00 AM             1
```

The output I'm trying to get is

```
year                             indicator_id           Diff
--------------------------      ---------------        ------
January 1, 1999, 12:00 AM             1                  0
January 1, 2000, 12:00 AM             1                  1
January 1, 2001, 12:00 AM             1                  1
January 1, 2006, 12:00 AM             1                  5
```

I've tried the following query but it just returns the same row with a difference of 0

```
SELECT indicator_id, 
       year, 
       year - lag(year) over (order by year) as Diff
FROM education_data
```

Please help

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: https://rextester.com/WRV58738 - is this something you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

> to find cases where the difference is not be more than 3 years.

If this is what you want, then use a subquery to get the previous value and filter in the outer query:

```
select ed.*
from (select ed.*, lag(year) over (order by year) as prev_year
      from education_data ed
     ) ed
where prev_year >= year - interval '3 year';
```